# UV unwrap skewed from center outwards

Tags: uv

When I unwrap my UV textures are getting skewed from the center outwards along all seams. I've tried to straighten them and "rectify" (square up) via TexTools, but no luck so far.

[image: skewed UVs]

[image]

[image][image]

Comment: do you have a Subdivision Surface modifier? In that case, under Advanced > UV Smooth, choose Keep Corners or another option

Comment: @moonboots Huge Thanks! It solved the issue! You have made my day!

Answer (score 1):

In your *Subdivision Surface* modifier, under *Advanced > UV Smooth*, choose *Keep Corners* or another option that works.