# how can i fix uv unwrapping issue?

Tags: uv

[image: screenshot]
Hi, I understand English badly but I really need some help. I added *Mark Seams*, applied all transformations, and for the subdivision, I've chosen *UV Smooth* to all but I still have this distortion after UV unwrapping and I don't know how to fix that. I tried so many methods on Youtube but no one is helping me.

Blend file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cjndxOh41WYNcBUAVGa0EOwguHG2v-nK/view?usp=sharing

Comment: maybe try that: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/274803/uv-unwrap-skewed-from-center-outwards/274813#274813

Comment: Could you provide the Blender file pls?

Comment: @Artichoke sure, im sorry for not to do this before https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cjndxOh41WYNcBUAVGa0EOwguHG2v-nK/view?usp=sharing

Comment: https://blend-exchange.com use this site, you can upload the file in this way

Answer (score 0):

You didn't apply the modifiers (you need to aplply the subdivision, bevel and mirror)  If you apply them and then you unwrapp (for example with Smart UV Project) you will find that there is no streching.
[image]

Comment: but if i apply modificators on  this way  this are changes my geometry, i mean thats was more strange in angles but if  i apply firstable subsurf after bevel and mirror thats chances my geometry, i need to apply firstable mirror after belev and subsurf